# Suppose $\kappa$ is a cardinal, such that $2 \kappa = \kappa$. Can it be proven that $\kappa ! = 2^\kappa$ without choice?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

The original question is given in an exercise. The first part of the problem is to show that if $\left|A\right| = \left|A\right| +\left|A\right|$ for some set $A$, then there exists a partition of $A$, with every cell in the partition having cardinality $2$ (i.e. a partition of $A$ into pairs). The second part of the problem is to show that the cardinality of the set of permutations of $A$ is $2^{\left|A\right|}$.

Using the first part of the problem, it's not hard to show that that cardinality of set of permutations of $A$ is bounded between $2^{\left|A\right|}$ and $\left|A\right|^{\left|A\right|}$. But I couldn't find a way to proceed from here without assuming that $\left|A\right| = \left|A\right|\cdot\left|A\right|$.

Is it possible to complete the proof without choice?

Comment: Is that an exercise in a book?

Comment: @bof No, it's from an exercise sheet given in a course. The exercise doesn't ask to avoid choice explicitly, but I thought it is implicit because the only assumption is that $\left|A\right| + \left|A\right| = \left|A\right|$, and because the next problem goes "In the previous problem we saw that  $\left|A\right|+\left|A\right|=\left|A\right|$ implies that $A$ can be partitioned to pairs. What partition can we find if $\left|A\right|\cdot\left|A\right|=\left|A\right|$?".